# Adding angular 2 component/module to website built with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, angular

Can someone clear this for me, is it possible to add angular 2 component to a website that's been built with asp.net mvc? This component, or module in this case will be part of the website and will act as a SPA.

If possible, can someone give me example via some article or youtube link how to add it...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's recommender use asp mvc as web api, and have separate backend and frontend. Angular call asp mvc endpoints.

How create a asp mvc web api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

With asp core mvc (new): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

Comment: I have a functioning web api with angular in it, now I'm not sure how is my angular component implemented back in the asp.net mvc since half of frontend is done with angular and half is not...

Comment: You can isolate a angular project from the rest of application, example, **www.mysite.com/angular-component/**
You will need set a base href, **/angular-component** in  **www.mysite.com/angular-component/index.html** file. I recommend you create angular project with angular cli.